# Devise Installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I keep getting errors while attempting to install the devise gem.

I am following instructions on: http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise

My steps:

1) I opened the 'Gemfile' file and added the following line:

```
gem 'devise', '~> 3.2.4'
```

2) I ran bundle install, which seemed to have worked correctly.

3) I run "rails generate devise_install", which however throws

"method_missing': undefined method `devise' for Install (call 'Install.connection' to establish a connection):Class (NoMethodError)"

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a colon was missing on the devise installation command. Try this

```
 rails generate devise:install
```

You should see something like this follow immediately after.

```
create  config/initializers/devise.rb
create  config/locales/devise.en.yml
```

With some further post installation instructions.